# How can I use CSS to vertically center the text in an anchor, within a LI?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Variations on this question have been asked many times. Vertical centering with CSS is a challenge.

I have a particular scenario, dealing with a list displayed horizontally. The markup is like this:

```
  <ul id='ul1' class='c'>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Fribble Fromme</a></li>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Fobble</a></li>
    <li><a href='javascript:void(0)'>Foo Fickle Pickle</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The style is like this:

```
  ul.c {
    height:52px;
    text-align:center;
  }
  ul li a {
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    border: 1px solid Maroon;
    padding:2px 12px;
    background:#FFEF8A;
    line-height:1em;
    width:100px;
  }
  ul li a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
  }
  ul li {
    height:52px;
    display:inline-block;
  }
```

The resulting list looks like this:

[image]

But I want all the boxes to be the same height, and I want the text to be vertically centered in each box.  I can set the box-height by adding a `height` style for the A elements.  The result looks like this:

[image]

...which is close to what I want, but the vertical-centering isn't happening.

I can set `line-height` for the text, [as suggested in this post](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/vertical-aligned-nav-list.html), to do the vertical centering. I can even pick different values of `line-height` for different A elements, if I know which of the elements will get multiple lines of text.  But I don't know which ones will require multiple lines.

How can I get it to center when some of the A elements have text that wraps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `display:table`, etc. along with `vertical-align:middle`

```
ul.c {
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
}

ul li {   
    float:left;    
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    border: 1px solid Maroon;
    padding:2px 12px;
    background:#FFEF8A;
    width:100px;
    height:52px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kf52n/2/

Answer (score 35):

Old question, but the answer can now be updated with Flexbox.

```
a {
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure a way to do this in CSS.  I found that *I could do what I needed* with Javascript, setting the `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to appropriate values at runtime.  The technique is to measure the "natural" height of the A element, then set the padding so that the A element is vertically centered.

here is the necessary js code:

```
  function setHeightIntelligently(ulElement) {
    var items, L1, i, anchor, availableHeight = ulElement.clientHeight,
        naturalHeight, pad;
    items = ulElement.children;
    for(i=0, L1 = items.length;i<L1;i++){
      if (items[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == 'LI') {
        anchor = items[i].children[0]; 
        naturalHeight = anchor.clientHeight;
        pad = (availableHeight - naturalHeight)/2;
        anchor.style.paddingTop= pad+'px';
        anchor.style.paddingBottom= pad+'px';
      }
    }
  }

  function init() {
    var element = document.getElementById('ul1');
    setHeightIntelligently(element);
  }
```

In the CSS, one must not explicitly set height or padding for the A elements. Doing that would cause the "natural" height to not be what we need it to be.

The result is like this:

[image]

To see it in action, [go here](http://jsfiddle.net/kf52n/1/).

Answer (score 0):

in the css you have set the height and line-height to the same. Then you will get a rectangular box.

But still you are seeing space in the bottom the reason is due to padding

adding two values in padding adds top and bottom padding

padding: top bottom;

since it is 2 and 12 you are seeing huge space.

try this

```
height: 52px;
line-height:52px;
padding: 6px 6px; // here you have to tweak and see the output
vertical-align:center;
```

let me know it is working

Comment: Can you set vertical align as center?

Comment: Seems to me the value for "vertical-align" can only be "middle", not "center"

Answer (score 0):

`line-height:250%;` worked for me